# Existence of area-preserving diffeomorphism between two sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geometric-topology

Suppose that we have open sets $A, B\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $A$ and $B$ are simply connected and have smooth boundaries. Furthermore, let us assume that $m(A) = m(B) > 0$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$. My question is as follows: when does there exist an area-preserving diffeomorphism between $A$ and $B$? In this context, an area-preserving diffeomorphism between $A$ and $B$ is a is a $C^{\infty}$-diffeomorphism $\phi : A\to B$ such that $m(S) = m(\phi(S))$ for all measurable $S\subseteq A$. If an area-preserving diffeomorphism doesn't always exist between sets $A$ and $B$ as above, are there any extra conditions we can impose on $A$ and $B$ such that there *does* exist an area-preserving diffeomorphism?

My thoughts thus far are that we always have a $C^{\infty}$-diffeomorphism between $A$ and $B$: this is a consequence of the [Riemann mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem). It's also obvious to me that if we can deform $A$ linearly to get $B$, then that deformation will be area-preserving. Furthermore, it seems that aside from this case, there's no reason why an area-preserving diffeomorphism should exist. However, I'm having a hard time proving that there necessarily *isn't* an area-preserving diffeomorphism between $A$ and $B$ if $B$ is not a linear deformation of $A$. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: This is a very special case of Moser's theorem.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely see why. For example, given a diffeomorphism $\phi : A\to B$, Moser's theorem guarantees a symplectomorphism $\psi$ between $(A, \omega)$ and $(A, (\phi^{-1})^*\omega)$ which is defined by $\psi^*(\phi^{-1})^*\omega = (\phi^{-1}\circ \psi)^*\omega = \omega$. This is satisfied by $\psi = \phi$, but there's no reason why $\phi$ should be area-preserving.

Comment: @MichaelLee You are using $\omega$ for the standard area form on both $A$ and $B$. These are not the same. In particular since $\phi : A \to B$ in doesn't make any sense to say $\phi$ gives a symplectomorphism from $A$ to $A$ with any forms.

Comment: I figured as much, since the conclusion made no sense. How does Moser's theorem guarantee an area-preserving diffeomorphism between $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @MichaelLee A version of Moser's theorem states that there is a symplectomorphism $f$ between $(A, \omega_A)$ and $(A, (\phi)^* \omega_B)$ where $\omega_A$ and $\omega_B$ are the restriction of the standard area form  on $A$ and $B$. Taking $g=\phi \circ f$ gives the desired symplectomorphism from $(A, \omega_A)$ to $(B, \omega_B)$. One has to be a little careful here that the flow given from Moser's argument does not push you off the disk (in other words we don't have long time existence for solutions to ODES in non-compact worlds).

Comment: The easiest fix I could think of was to use the Lagrangian neighborhood theorem to guarantee your diffeo. was already area preserving near the boundary (so symplectomorphism would be fixed near there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See

[Diffeomorphisms and volume-preserving embeddings of noncompact manifolds](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1979-255-00/S0002-9947-1979-0542888-3/),
by R. E. Greene and K. Shiohama, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 255 (1979), 403-414.

They prove a version of Moser's theorem for noncompact manifolds of any dimension.  In your setting, it yields a volume-preserving diffeomorphism.